# Overload typings with Python *args in super class

Tags: python, typing, mypy

I have a simple base class as follows:

```py
class Base:
  def get(self, *names: str) -> Any:
    # implementation not important
```

I'm trying to define a subclass with stricter typing for some use cases:

```py
from typing import overload, Any
from typing_extensions import Literal

class Sub(Base):
  # mypy error here: Signature of "get" incompatible with supertype "Base"
  @overload
  def get(self, *names: Literal['Something']) -> Something: ...
  @overload
  def get(self, *names: Literal['Else']) -> Else: ...
  def get(self, *names: str) -> Any:
    return super().get(*names)
```

However, I get the error noted in the code above: `Signature of "get" incompatible with supertype "Base"`. I've tried other forms for the arguments of the overload for the `Sub` class, but all generate a similar error.

Is there anyway, for a base class method that takes `*args`, to provide specific overloads in a subclass when literal values are passed in?

Comment: Do you have a reference for that @chepner? Just curious cause [the mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html#when-you-re-puzzled-or-when-things-are-complicated) give this example: `def call(self, *args: str, **kwargs: str) -> str:` with the note: "This makes each positional arg and each keyword arg a "str""

Comment: Where does `@overload` get defined. Does `mypy` know about it?

Comment: It's part of the [python typing spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading), and [understood by mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#function-overloading). Good call out though, I added the import to the OP to make it clearer for readers

Comment: Also worth noting that `typing.Literal` is only introduced in the not-yet-released Python 3.8. Could this simply be a bug in `mypy`?

Comment: [`mypy` is able to handle `Literal`](http://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2019/01/mypy-0660-released.html) as long as you have `typing-extension` `3.7.2` or greater installed. You might be right though, this may be a mypy bug (or I might just be typing things wrong haha ;) )

Answer (score 2):

The correct typings for `Sub` should look something like this:

```py
class Sub(Base):
  @overload
  def get(self, __name: Literal['Something']) -> Something: ...
  @overload
  def get(self, __name: Literal['Else']) -> Else: ...
  @overload
  def get(self, *names: str) -> Any: ...
  def get(self, *names: str) -> Any:
    return super().get(*names)
```

There are a few changes here compared to the question.

1) We define an additional overload that has types identical to the implementation. The [python docs for `@overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) explain this: "the [non-@overload-decorated definition] is used at runtime but should be ignored by a type checker."

2) Nobody would pass the same literal more than once, so we might as well change `*names` to `__name`. The leading underscores indicate that `name` is 'positional-only', as described [in the mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html#functions):

```py
# An argument can be declared positional-only by giving it a name
# starting with two underscores:
def quux(__x: int) -> None:
    pass

quux(3)  # Fine
quux(__x=3)  # Error
```

With the above changes, out `Sub` class typechecks as desired.